# Do Angular JS $http promises to behave like true $q promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-service

I'm aware that Angular can handle promises from within controllers.  For example:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myvar = getDeferredPromise();
}
```

The main angular digest loop handles this gracefully, assigning whatever value the deferred function finally returns later to **myvar**.

However, although the **$http.get()** method returns a promise, I cannot get it to work in this way.  For example:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.myvar = $http.get('/url');
}
```

The 'promise' the get method returns has a ***success*** method which takes a function that is assigned the data that one would wish to assign to **myvar**.

However, it also has a ***then*** method - but that is given the entire response object - not just that data part!  This is what seems to end up getting assigned to **myvar**!

This fiddle may help: http://jsfiddle.net/QKnNC/1/

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this somehow 'by design'?

Comment: I guess it's by design: Promises do usually fulfill with only one value, so you will need to pass the whole response object to make it accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a
>   configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and
>   returns a promise with two $http specific methods: success and error.

`$http` returns a promise, so you need to chain `then` to get the data.

```
IPService.getV1().then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
    $scope.value1 = response.data;
});
```

Comment: @Rik. Yes. If you use $resource, it returns a wrapped promise, which can be applied to scope directly.

Comment: Firstly, your example above is functionally similar to my getV2 method. Also, is it not sensible to keep that inside the service, and not expose the entire response object to the controller?

Comment: R.e. $resource: that's very interesting!  Hadn't come across that service!  Will go and have a play!  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`then` is the general promise function, that takes a success and error callback and you get the resolved value, whatever it may be. `success` and `error` are `$http` specific, and are aliases for `then` with one exception: they set a bunch of useful arguments rather than just the data. See [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.2/src/ng/http.js#L673).

Answer (score 0):

It is by design.  Your `getV2()` method is what you want.  Since you are using GET, you could save the result of your promise and return that on subsequent calls to `getV2()`:

```
var v2promise, v2data;
return {
   getV2: function() {
      if(!v2promise) {
        v2promise = $http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com/').then(
          function(response) {
             v2data = response.data;
             return v2data;
        });
      }
      return v2promise;
   }
}
```